# i want to know the life of a custom function in powershell

Tags: powershell

```bsh
function delete_Users
{
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $Users = Import-Csv C:\temp\test.csv
    
    ForEach ($User in $Users)
    {
        # Retrieve user to make sure they exist.
        $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.sAMAccountName
        If ($ADUser)
        {
            # Delete the user.
            Remove-ADUser -Identity $User.sAMAccountName
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to add this code in custom menu of powershell ISE.Can some one please let me knew how to do this. I tried this piece of code but it didn't worked for me.

```bsh
#to add the function in custom menu option

$psISE.CustomMenu.Submenus.Add(“Run Custom Function”,{delete_Users},Ctrl+Shift+0)
```

Moreover what would be the life of that custom function? Would it remain there even after closing the session or after shutting down the server or is there any specific way to achieve this.
Thank you in Advance..

Comment: Please elaborate on "it didn't worked for me" - does nothing happen? Does _anything_ happen? If so, what? Errors? Please show us the errors :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My motive was to define the frequently used functions in custom function category so that i can use them again n again. Neither I  am able to add this function to custom function category. I run this code to add the delete_users function category but it didn't saved. Can you please let me know the way by which i can easily add such functions in custom functions.

Comment: Right but _what happens when you run the code_? For reference, when I paste your code into ISE it throws 3 parser errors because of an `"Unexpected token 'Ctrl+Shift+0' in expression or statement."`

Comment: I would not put destructive code like that in the menu or under a hotkey **ever**, but there are blogs on how to put code in your profile file and add these functions to the ISE menus. For instance [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/adding-custom-menu-items-to-the-windows-powershell-ise/), or [here](https://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-ise-multiline-comment-and-uncomment-done-right-and-other-ise-gui-must-haves/) or [there](https://petri.com/using-addonsmenu-property-powershell-ise-object-model)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for sharing the link..got the answer of my problem.